# How would I properly structure this database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I am new to database design and would really appreciate it if you gave me the TL;DR of good database design and how I would apply it to my own project.

I need to design a database that will consist of

- Employees
- Employers
- Employer settings
- Employee settings
- Messages
- Employee tasks and
- Employee locations.

The way that I was thinking of going about it was creating an

- Employers table
- Employee table
- Employer settings table which references employees by id
- Employee settings table
  and relate the rest of the tables to the employees by id.

Is this a good idea?

Comment: What do you mean by employer/employee settings?

Comment: settings for employers and settings for employees for their separate and different control panels

Comment: Are emplyer and employee both persons? Can an employee also be an employer? Do their (possible) settings differ very much?

Comment: an employer is a "parent" of employees, I am actually going to refer to employers as organizations they have two very different "portals" where employers have more of an administrative like interface while employees get only personal pages. The employer can also give employees privileges and access to other portions of the application through the employer's settings.

Comment: The TL;DR of good database design: don't think code; think data. For now, forget about "portals", they don't exist in database land. EXAMPLE: replace {employers,employees} by {circles,ellipses}. My question: are circles and ellipses really different? Your answer: they have different portals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Employers table.

Assuming this is not a person, but a company.

- Employee table

Include employer id for employee's designation. You can use separate table for this.

- Employer settings table

Focus more about the employer, and never relate this with employee

- Employee settings table
- Messages table

Include the message, employer id, and employee id in which the message is addressed

- Employee tasks table

Include the task, employer id, and employee id in which the task is addressed

- Employee locations table

This is mandatory if location has multiple values per employee. If not, you can include location on employee or employee settings table

Comment: ya, I thought that the table relations go without saying, I should have been more explicit. Aside from that, I want to save employee locations as they report it so that the employer can look at the employee's route, etc. Also, I want to take statistics of employees (have a statistics page for every employee), should I save the values or just generate them on the fly?

Comment: You should definitely save the location values with date. You can also have time spent (per hour in integer values). EDIT: you can declare datetime start and datetime end per location

Answer (score 0):

The idea is good. If you're new to Db design I would recommend you to pay more attention on:

1. Defining references keys properly so data does get lost by accident
2. Manage created/updated timestamps for each record
3. Try to look ahead. i.e. What happens if employee changed his employer? maybe you need to persist effective from/to dates of employment rather that simple ID reference. Having full history of data in DB is always good idea.